# How can I use a variable from a different method in the same class without putting it as a parameter?

Tags: python

I have a class called "save", and it is a child of class "budget". I have a variable called saving and I want to use that in multiple methods of class "save".

This is the chunk of code:

```
class save(budget):

    def show(self):
        print('you have this much money to save:')
        saving = saving+(self.money * 0.4)
        print(saving)

    def spend(self):
        saved = int(input('How much have you set aside to save from this paycheck?'))
        saving = saving-saved
        print('This is how much you need to save: '+str(self.money))
```

I would also prefer a solution without using the keyword global.

Comment: aren't the functions , member functions of class save? a variable within the class should be accessed by the member functions.

Comment: Whenever I run my code, it shows the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'saving' referenced before assignment". I tried using global, but my teacher wanted a solutoin without it.

Comment: To make your variable available across your methods you need to make it a variable of the class. Declare it using `self.saving` instead of `saving`. This will make it part of the class.

Comment: Is the saving variable outside of the class scope? Or it can be declared inside the class as saving=0

Comment: Make it an instance variable, just like `money` (except not inherited from `budget`).  Add an `__init__` method, which calls the parent's `__init__` and also initializes `saving` to zero.

Comment: Did you notice the comment I added to the bottom of my answer?  I don't know if this comment might cause you to check it out if you haven't yet.  Hope so.

Comment: @CryptoFool yes I did see it. My program is a budgeter in which it asks you how much you have spent and takes that much away from the set amount you can spend. It then informes you on how much money you can spend on something (e.g: food, games, etc). But thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an illustration of how to do this, as @TomKarzes correctly outlines:

```
class save(budget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.saving = 0

    def show(self):
        print('you have this much money to save:')
        self.saving = self.saving+(self.money * 0.4)
        print(self.saving)

    def spend(self):
        saved = int(input('How much have you set aside to save from this paycheck?'))
        self.saving = self.saving-saved
        print('This is how much you need to save: '+str(self.money))
```

One thing about your code, assuming this is the logic you expected...your `show()` method changes the value of the `self.saving` variable each time it is called.  I wouldn't expect that from a method with that name, so I wonder if maybe you mean:

```
def show(self):
    print('you have this much money to save:')
    print(self.saving+(self.money * 0.4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class save(budget):

    def __init__(self, amount):  
        self.saving = amount 

    def show(self):
        print('you have this much money to save:')
        self.saving += (self.money * 0.4)
        print(self.saving)

    def spend(self):
        saved = int(input('How much have you set aside to save from this paycheck?'))
        self.saving -= saved
        print('This is how much you need to save: '+str(self.money))

account=save(500)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Unless you know that the `budget` class has no necessary logic in its constructor (`__init__` method), you need to call that method explicitly from the subclass's constructor.  The logic within the superclass constructor is not executed automatically, as `__init__` acts like any other overridden method.